# How to disable text box after it is edited in windows phone app 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to create a text box which will be disabled to edit after the value is entered at the first time in windows 8.1 phone app. How could it be done?

Comment: Have any of the answers been useful to you ?. If so you should mark one of them as accepted so that future users know that it worked for you. If not you should ask for more details or explanations

Comment: Yeah, checked just now. Marked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to know about `LostFocus` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.lostfocus.aspx) event and `IsEnabled` property (https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.controls.control.isenabled%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

```
private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var textbox = (TextBox)sender;
    textbox.IsEnabled = !(textbox.Text.Length > 0 && textbox.IsEnabled);
}
```